# Pin messages to stay always on top with Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, plugins

How can I make Thunderbird to pin selected emails to stay always on top?
I can't find this feature in Thunderbird, there is a pin icon but it looks like it only "keeps the filtering when changing folders", whose function is not too clear to me. Also, suggestions on this (and possibly other) add-ons are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work this way in Thunderbird. Instead you can "Star" messages, then use "Quickfilter" to quickly only displays the starred messages to give them attention. Works very intuitive and efficiently as well, a bit as the labels in gmail.

Comment: So there is no way to do that? I have tried out your suggestion and it makes some sense, but it's definitely different from having those important messages always at the top of the list, where you don't need any actions to remind you of those messages.

Comment: No, there is no way to have messages always sorted on top.

Comment: Pinning in Outlook always annoyed me, taking up valuable screen lines. The Thunderbird method of starring, and then simply one-click sorting by star, makes the e-mail window more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Like vanadium said, you mark messages with a star.

But you can also sort your messages by being marked by clicking on the star in the header. Marked messages will therefore always appear on top (or bottom depending on the sort order).

Thunderbird should still keep your current order for all unmarked and new messages (like a second-level ordering criteria).